# C++ Reading in data with different column lengths

Tags: c++

I was previously reading in data with columns that were all the same length with an answer I found here.

**Data:**

```
0.001    0.001    0
0.001    0.001    0
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::vector<double> heights, times, stdDevs;
std::ifstream data ("inputData.dat");
std::string line;
double var1, var2, var3;

if (data.is_open())
{
    while (getline(data,line))
    {
        std::istringstream(line) >> var1 >> var2 >> var3;
        heights.push_back(var1);
        times.push_back(var2);
        stdDevs.push_back(var3);
    }
}
```

However, now I have data of different column lengths and more columns than before. **New Data:**

```
0.001    0.001    0        0.002    0.000    0.001    0    0.002 
         0.001    0.001    0.002    0.001    0.001    0    0.002
         0.002             0.003    0.001    0.002    0    0.003
         0.003             0.005             0.003    0    0.004
```

**My thoughts:**

- I can't append zeros to the columns to make them all the same size since that'll mess with the data.
- I thought about reading in the data like before, except first finding out how many rows/columns first and then creating an array to store everything so I can use loops instead of var1 >> var2 >> etc.
- The data is non-decreasing, so I thought I could find the max value of each column and use this to determine the length of data in each column.

Do y'all have any suggestions, or could I get some help with how to read in so many columns with loops? Thanks.

**Edit:** I tried this out to determine the overall size, since every column starts with something:

```
if (data.is_open())
{
    getline(data,line);
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < line.length(); ++k)
    {
        if(!isspace(line[k])){ j++; } //How many columns 
    }

    while (getline(data,line))
    {
        i += 1; //How many rows
    }
```

Now I'm going to try my max idea.

Comment: What are the separator characters?  Are there two consecutive when column data is missing?

Comment: Your sample has spaces as separators. If the column spacing is a given, then you only have to `read` one data item at a time.

Comment: Good question, the separator characters are tabs and yes there are two consecutive tabs when column data is missing. I cleaned it up for clarity but should've mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

First, better to do all the reading in one scan for the efficiency considerations. You can organise one getline() loop for this.

1) If the first row defines the max number of columns for the whole table, you can read it to detect this number and define proper arrays.

2) You need to decide, what to put to array element in case of absence of a value. If all the expected numbers are > 0, you can take -1.0, for instance, or DBL_MAX.

3) "to determine the length of data in each column" - why you need this? Assuming these all are double values, you can just read them in the elements of array of doubles - you don't need temporary variables.

Comment: 1) Okay yeah my edit above shows what I did to determine the max number of columns like you said. 2)-1.0 seems like a good idea and I'll look into DBL_MAX. 3) Well I guess when I use the data later, I want to read the column up to the end so I wanted the size, but if I use something like -1 like you say, I can stop there. Thanks!